# Check if String contains regex match

Tags: java, regex

What i want is to check if there is a number followed by spaces and another number, without any `","` in between, anywhere in the `String`

Currently i am doing this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9][\" \"]+[0-9]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if(matcher.find()) return false;
```

and it works just fine. But i was wondering if there is any other simpler way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's an assignment, I won't write out the code, but an alternative solution is:

- Split the string on the `,` token (using `String.split()`)
- For each member of the resulting split array:

  - Trim the leading and trailing spaces from the member
  - If the trimmed member is an integer (I'll let you figure out how to determine that):

    - It doesn't meet the criteria you specified
  - Else:

    - It's possible that the token could meet your criteria (of containing multiple integers and spaces but no commas. There are several ways you could determine this: do a split on `" "`; use a `while` loop, or maybe something else. I'll let you figure that out.

Comment: No, in that case, `split[0]` would be `1 2` (the space would be preserved), which of course isn't an integer.

Comment: Ah, I think I was trying to just check if each token is an integer, but you're looking for the case where two or more integers are *not* properly separated. I updated my answer, that should be more than enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is good enough, you could try by the positive way like

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[1-9](,[1-9])*$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if(matcher.matches()) return true;
```